# Best way to store a timestamp requested by a lot of users at the same time

Tags: php, mysql, performance

**Let's say i have a timestamp (like : 1505148597) representing the last message posted in a tchat.**

Then i have about 10000 users requesting /lastTimestamp.php every second. This page returns the timestamp so users know if they have to fetch new messages.

**Should I :**

**a)** store the timestamp in database and make a sql request everytime a user calls /lastMessageTimestamp.php to return it

**b)** store the timestamp in a file on the server and open it everytime a user calls /lastMessageTimestamp.php to return it

**c)** store it in memory and access it somehow ?

**What is the most optimized way to do it ? My biggest concern is performance and server load.**

Note : i'm not looking for another way to do a tchat, this is the way i want to do it, i just want to know what the best solution is to make it (the example is very simplified), it's not even for a tchat. In fact i'm using Server Sent Events, so basically the 10k users are opening a stream with the server, and server is doing a

```
while(1) { 
   //check the timestamp with one of the solutions
   sleep(1);
}
```

Comment: More interesting question is how you are going to maintain this value current when hundreds of users are chatting (i.e. adding messages).

Comment: You're processing 10,000 requests/second on one server.... that's pretty impressive, must be one heck of a box

Comment: Well please read the entire post, you will understand that's not the case, i just made the example more simple

Comment: If you're operating at this level and haven't heard of memory based key value stores, I'm a bit concerned.  Look at redis and memcached.

Comment: i heard about memcached, that could be the solution too

Comment: I would recommend using something with a persistent connection.. look into nodejs perhaps.

Comment: That's what i do ! please read the last part of my post

Comment: 10000 users checking a value from a db is insane, when you think of the response according to this rate, using a file wouldn't be wise, db is much better. Instead of ordering by date and getting timestamp would be exhausting for mysql. In this case, as @Devon pointed if memcached is not an option you may save to a single column that you know the id of it, is faster. or more wisely websockets. Like http://socket.io/

Comment: Alright, and i'm already using SSE (see the last part of my post) which is enough for what i want to do (serv > client). I'm gonna check memcached or redis

Comment: no support for ms clients though :(

Comment: SSE doesn't give you a leverage at this point you just running an infinite loop that checks your value. Correct me if I am wrong but, still amount of user and running script instances are the same. You're just not sending http request instead have one standalone connection and that checks a value from database or whatever your source is. on the other hand with nodejs a client can update server and notify other clients.

Comment: Indeed, it's still better to not have 10000 http request/sec, but i agree that the while for every user is overkill too.. I can't use node.js that's why i was looking for an alternative where i don't have to request the database for the 10k users in the while

Comment: Sounds like you need push technology, not polling.

Answer (score 0):

You should put a caching layer in front to handle the load. I would suggest Redis: https://redis.io/

Comment: that's what i'm planning now. It will still be better than requesting the database for 10k users/sec

Answer (score 0):

This is the best example use of a memory store => store once retrieve many times. You always store the last timestamp (once).

Either:
`apcu` 
[apc_store](http://php.net/manual/en/function.apc-store.php)
or

`memcached`
[Memcached::set](http://php.net/manual/en/memcached.set.php)

Memcached is a little more complex to set up, but can help in very high volume scenarios

Comment: Thanks, i wanted to use memcached or redis, but i can't since i'm not on a dedicated server

Comment: Then test to see if APC is installed (it usually is). That would really sped things up.